# How can I get the properties from API call?

Tags: ionic3, angular2-routing

I'm new to ionic and angular. I'm doing the API Call from news API. I need a specific property from the data to show like `{{ data.author }}`.

I get the data at console page by:

```js
var.subscribe( data =>{
    console.log(data)
});
```

This my function code:

```js
export class Home Page {
    news list:[];
    public API: string="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=MY_KEY"

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get(this.API).subscribe(articles => {
            return articles;
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

This is my html code:

```html
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-title>Sample</ion-title>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let articles of newslist">
            <h2> {{ articles.title }} </h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I don't know exact what to do. So please help me to find and learn how to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `articles` as a class property, which be valued by the API call response :

```js
export class HomePage {
  ...
  articles: any = []; // I let you choose the right response type
  ...

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: HttpClient) {
   this.http.get(this.API).subscribe(articles => {
     this.articles = articles; 
  });
  ...
}
```

Now, `articles` is accessible in the HTML template :

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-title>Sample</ion-title>
  <ion-list *ngIf="articles?.length">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let article of articles">
      <h2> {{ article.title }} </h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>'
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. It's show a error in console log following.

Comment: console page error were added above. I need that API data's specified property in filter like if i'll provide {{ data.author }} it only shows the author name from the API article.

Comment: You can't post the log from my response as a new answer. You could just have write in this thread `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Comment: Just check that `articles` has correctly been initialized as an empty array : `articles: any = [];`

Comment: okay this is the first experience here that's why i did that...:-).

Comment: Yes the articles initialized with empty array. how do i choose the correct response type.

Comment: As `any` it shouldn't be related to the error you got. Maybe you could try to add `?` to `articles` in the HTML, I'll edit my answer

Comment: It shows error-Error:static injector error [HttpClient] Null injector error : No provider for [Httpclient]

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

**page.ts**

```
export interface ArticlesList {
author: string;
  content: string;
  description: string;
  publishedAt: string;
  source: any;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
  urlToImage: string;
}
export class HomePage {
  ...
  public API: string="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=7f26759a25004b16b1563bcb52ea8481"
  public newsList: any;
  ...

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http: HttpClient) {
   this.articlesData();
 }
articlesData() {
        return new Promise<ArticlesList>(resolve => {
        this.httpClient.get(this.API)
            .subscribe((res: any) => {
            resolve(res);
            console.log(res);
            this.newsList = res.articles;
            }, err => {
            console.log(err);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

**page.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let news of newsList">
        <h2 style="font-size: 14px"> {{ news.title }} </h2>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Hope it helps you :)